# matlab2tikz: pgfplots surf with patchmap causing missing number

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I try to convert a MATLAB `surf` into a `pgfplots` plot using `matlab2tikz`. It does not compile with the error

```
<to be read again> 
\pgfpl@cm@surfmap@X@size 
l.44 };
```

Do I miss provide a parameter or is there an incompatibility?
An MWE is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% and optionally (as of Pgfplots 1.3):
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8.558cm,
height=6cm,
at={(0cm,0cm)},
scale only axis,
colormap={patchmap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.683515,0.87866,0.82487); rgb(1pt)=(0.992077,0.96963,0.951899); rgb(2pt)=(0.992355,0.970696,0.953586); rgb(3pt)=(0.993884,0.976557,0.962869); rgb(4pt)=(0.588067,0.842065,0.772053); rgb(5pt)=(0.947739,0.799666,0.6827); rgb(6pt)=(0.999305,0.997336,0.995781); rgb(7pt)=(0.951353,0.813519,0.704641); rgb(8pt)=(0.87776,0.953133,0.932357)},
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
ymin=0,
ymax=2,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids
]

\addplot[%
surf,
shader=flat corner, draw=black, mesh/rows=3]
table[row sep=crcr, colormap name=surfmap, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   c\\
0   0   0\\
0   1   1\\
0   2   2\\
1   0   3\\
1   1   4\\
1   2   5\\
2   0   6\\
2   1   7\\
2   2   8\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Re-added `\\` to line `2 2 8` in the MWE not into the Runaway argument issue. This fixes it for `pdflatex`, while the `lualatex` issue persists.

Comment: I get a different error: `Runaway argument? 2 2 8 \pgfplotstable@EOI \pgfplotstableread@impl@fCLOSE \pgfplotstableread@finish \ETC.`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Wouldn't that indicate imbalanced braces or something similar? In case it is of interest, I'm using `lualatex` with `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux)`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner is right, using `pdflatex`, I get the same error, while my error relatex to `lualatex`. (I'll keep that typo for beauty reasons…)

Comment: After further tests, the problem persists with `lualatex`. The error is accompanied with `Package pgfplots info on input line 44: Using 'lua backend=false' for plot 0 (t
ype 'mesh'): point meta choice does not support LUA.`

Comment: As a quick fix: You could generate the diagram with pdflatex and then just include the PDF into your luatex project.

Comment: That's what I'll try. Thank you for your thoughts!